# Jetty : Jetty server shutsdown

Tags: jetty

In a high concurrenet and traffic  Multithreaded Environment , We observed that the Jetty Server is  being stopped after sometime .

We are uisng Jetty 8

DOnt know what is the cause , and unable to reproduce manually ,  does  anybody know what time make Jetty server makes it shutsdown automatically .

Comment: Jetty shutsdown automatically or restarts automatically? If scanIntervalSeconds is greated than zero then it will look for code changes every `scanIntervalSeconds` period and auto-deployed(and hence restarts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty should not stop automatically in any case. So first of all, some questions:

- Which OS?
- Which JVM?
- Which exact Jetty Version?
- What does "sometime" mean. Minutes, Hours, Days?
- Just to be sure: What do you mean with shutdown? Does the jetty process disappear or does it stop responding to requests?

Any hint in STDOUT or in the logs about what might have caused the shutdown? What are the last log messages in STDOUT and request log?

If you have no log entries at all, it might be worth to throw threaddumps on a regular basis with some script. Every minute for example. You can use jstack or "kill -3 " (SIGHUP) to do so.